# How to remove `&` sign and all text after that from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this URL

```
https://myApp-ajj.com/sp?id=cat_item&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sys_id1=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sysp_Id=a691acd9dbdf1bc0e9619fb&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request
```

Here I am getting `sys_id` two times with different parameters. So I need to remove the second `&` sign and all text after that.

I tried this

```
location.href.split('&')[2]
```

I am sure it doesn't work. Can anyone provide some better solution?

Comment: `window.location.href`

Comment: My first question would be why does the url have two parameters with the same name

Comment: Having the same parameters twice or more is not invalidating URLs. Why would you need to remove it?

Comment: `a = '&sys_id'
b = location.href.split(a)
c = b[0]+a+b[1]`

Comment: @mjwatts they are not same parameters.it may vary,please check my updated question

Comment: @krish please check my answer

Comment: Keep in mind the parameters may change order so if you just trim everything after the second & you may lose data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you should `split` the string into an array then use `slice` to set the starting index number of the element which is 2 in your case and then `join` the array again into the string.

Read more about these methods [JavaScript String split() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), [jQuery slice() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_slice.asp) and [JavaScript Array join() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

```js
var url = 'https://myApp-ajj.com/sp?id=cat_item&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sysp_Id=a691acd9dbdf1bc0e9619fb&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request';

url = url.split("&").slice(0,2).join("&");
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```js
var url='https://myApp-ajj.com/sp?id=cat_item&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sysp_Id=a691acd9dbdf1bc0e9619fb&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request';

var first=url.indexOf('&');
var second=url.indexOf('&',first+1);
var new_url=url.substring(0,second);
console.log(new_url);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the 2nd occurrence of `&sys_id`. From there onwards remove all text.

Below is working code:

```js
let url='https://myApp-ajj.com/sp?id=cat_item&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sysp_Id=a691acd9dbdf1bc0e9619fb&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request';

let str1=url.indexOf('&sys_id');
let str2=url.indexOf('&sys_id',str1+1);
console.log(url.substring(0,str2));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var url = "https://myApp-ajj.com/sp?id=cat_item&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sys_id1=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sysp_Id=a691acd9dbdf1bc0e9619fb&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request"
url = url.slice(0, url.indexOf('&', url.indexOf('&') + 1));
console.log(url);
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit more verbose, but it handles all duplicate query params regardless of their position in the URL.

```js
function removeDuplicateQueryParams(url) {
  var params = {};
  var parsedParams = '';
  var hash = url.split('#'); // account for hashes
  var parts = hash[0].split('?');
  var origin = parts[0];
  var retURL;
  
  // iterate over all query params
  parts[1].split('&').forEach(function(param){
    // Since Objects can only have one key of the same name, this will inherently
    // filter out duplicates and keep only the latest value.
    // The key is param[0] and value is param[1].
    param = param.split('=');
    params[param[0]] = param[1];
  });
  
  Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key, ndx){
    parsedParams += (ndx === 0)
      ? '?' + key +'='+ params[key]
      : '&' + key +'='+ params[key];
  });
  
  return origin + parsedParams + (hash[1] ? '#'+hash[1] : '');
}

console.log( removeDuplicateQueryParams('http://fake.com?q1=fu&bar=fu&q1=fu&q1=diff') );
console.log( removeDuplicateQueryParams('http://fake.com?q1=fu&bar=fu&q1=fu&q1=diff#withHash') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var yourUrl = "https://myApp-ajj.com/sp?id=cat_item&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sysp_Id=a691acd9dbdf1bc0e9619fb&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request"
var indexOfFirstAmpersand = yourUrl.search("&"); //find index of first &
var indexOfSecondAmpersand = indexOfFirstAmpersand + yourUrl.substring((indexOfFirstAmpersand + 1)).search("&") + 1; //get index of second &
var fixedUrl = yourUrl.substring(0, indexOfSecondAmpersand)
$(".answer").text(fixedUrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="answer">
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the url using [`String.prototype.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) method. In the example below I created a function that takes a url string and checks for a duplicate parameter - it returns a new string with the second occurrence removed.

```js
var url = "https://myApp-ajj.com/sp?id=cat_item&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sys_id=cf9f149cdbd25f00d080591e5e961920&sysp_Id=a691acd9dbdf1bc0e9619fb&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request&sysparm_CloneTable=sc_request";

function stripDuplicateUrlParameter(url, parameterName) {
  //get the start index of the repeat occurrance
  var repeatIdx = url.lastIndexOf('sys_id');
  var prefix = url.substring(0, repeatIdx);
  var suffix = url.substring(repeatIdx);
  //remove the duplicate part from the string
  suffix = suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf('&') + 1);

  return prefix + suffix;
}

console.log(stripDuplicateUrlParameter(url));
```

This solves your specific problem, but wouldn't work if the parameter occurred more than twice or if the second occurrence of the string wasn't immediately following the first - you would probably write something more sophisticated.

As someone already asked - why is the url parameter being duplicated in the string anyway? Is there some way to fix that? (because the question asked seems to me to be a band-aid solution with this being the **root** issue).